# How to implement dynamically loaded script functionality with retries and returns

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to implement a function to dynamically load js scripts, if the loading fails, retry it, the retry limit is three times, and return the loading result.

```
async function getScript(url: string, retryTime = 0, promise?: any) {
  const element = window.document.createElement('script');
  element.src = url;
  element.type = 'text/javascript';
  element.async = true;

  const p = promise || {
    resolve: (v: boolean) => { },
    reject: (msg: string) => { },
  };

  element.onload = () => {
    p.resolve(true);
  };

  element.onerror = () => {
    const msg = `Dynamic Script Error: ${url}`;
    if (retryTime < 3) {
      console.log('retry load');
      document.head.removeChild(element);
      return getScript(url, retryTime + 1, p);
    }
    p.reject(msg);
  };
  document.head.appendChild(element);
  return new Promise((rl, rj) => {
    p.resolve = rl;
    p.reject = rj;
  });
}
```

But when I call this function, if load error in first time, and success in second time. `document.head.appendChild(element)`will throw an error, So, i can't catch the error in outside.

What can I do.

Comment: I'm curious as to the use-case for this. Why not just use '<link rel="preload">'

Comment: @CliffordCheefoon It's a dynamic scene, I need to do sth get user's version first. So I don't know the script's url at beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems overly complicated. Here's a cleaner, more decoupled solution:

```
async function getScript(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const element = document.createElement('script');
    element.src = url;
    element.type = 'text/javascript';
    element.async = true;
    element.onload = () => resolve();
    element.onerror = () => reject();
    document.head.appendChild(element);
  });
}

async function retrying(func, attempts) {
  for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= attempts; attempt++) {
    try {
      return await func();
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn(`Failed in attempt ${attempt}`);
    }
  }
  throw new Error(`Failed after ${attempts} attempts`);
}
```

Usage:

```
retrying(() => getScript(url), 3);
```

Comment: Just need to change
    element.onload(() => resolve());
    element.onerror(() => reject());
to 
    element.onload = () => resolve();
    element.onerror = () => reject();

Comment: Pardon me, edited.